# Given a set of points, find smallest subset of points from which circles of n diameter can be drawn to encompass all points

Tags: python-2.7, geometry, latitude-longitude

I've got a list of places with associated lat/lon data (sites).  I'm trying to find the fewest bases from which to visit the sites (minimizing travel occurrences).  Any ideas?  I've mostly been working with Python (2.7.3), but any suggestions/examples are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This can be viewed as the [set cover problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem).

Using Wikipedia's terminology, your universe will be the cities. If there are `m` cities, there will be `m` sets. `k`-th set will correspond to the `k`-th city and will include all cities within the required travel radius from `k`, including `k` itself. The task is to find the smallest number of sets that cover the universe (put another way, the smallest number of cities from which you can reach every city in your universe).

The bad news is that the problem is NP-hard. There are, however, [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Greedy_algorithm).

Comment: I'd vote this up, but I don't have enough reputation; Thanks.